# How to reload part of a form with jquery javascript?

Tags: jquery, refresh

How to refresh only an element of a HTML page with Jquery or Javascript on clicking another element on the same page? I need to know this to implement a form captcha.

```
<img src="includes/captcha.php" style="padding:10px 0;"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<img src="images/refresh.gif" onclick="window.location.reload()" style="cursor:pointer; padding:10px 0;" />
```

i want to reload the image generated wih captcha.php by clicking on refresh.gif. The current code reloads the complete page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not require any jquery. Simply alter the images `src` attribute to include some additional random data.

```
function reloadImage() {
    var now = new Date();
    document.getElementById('captcha').src = 'includes/captcha.php?r=' + now.getTime();
}
```

Alter your image tag to set an ID like this.

```
<img src="includes/captcha.php" id="captcha" style="padding:10px 0;"/>
```

And add the call to the function in your refresh image.

```
<img src="images/refresh.gif" onclick="reloadImage()" style="cursor:pointer; padding:10px 0;" />
```

Comment: Should i get and process the additional data in captcha.php? Its not working!

Comment: No, the point is simply to alter the URL so that the browser will reload the image. The additional `r` parameter should do nothing at all. Whoops, silly me forgot a new date. Edited the answer now

Comment: yup new date object. I am a fool i didn't notice that. My issue is solved here. Thank You a lot!!!

Answer (score 1):

What you need to use is the jQuery function load()

For instance if you want to replace the contents of a div with id='myDiv' with the contents of a div with id='theirDiv' from the HTML of a remote page, do this:

$('#myDiv').load('http://theirurl #theirDiv');

See

[http://api.jquery.com/load](http://api.jquery.com/load/)